# Any simpler and more efficient way of writing this code?

Tags: php, php5

I've noticed I've got quite a few repeated lines in my code.

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2014);
$rate = 1 / 30;
$amount = number_format(floor((time() - $start) * $rate));

$id = array(
    array("42706686", "rebel2america"),
    array("100004055720670", "marquez.candace"),
    array("100000756492404", "vince.goode.3"),
    array("100007763585373", "laura.allen.75491"),
);

// 70% chance of red an 30% of green
$status = array(
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("green", "yes"),
    array("green", "yes"),
    array("green", "yes")
);

$online = range(7, 21);

// create and assign a 'seed' value that changes 
// every $duration and assign to mt_srand
$duration = 5;
$mins = date('i', strtotime('now'));
$seed = $mins - ($mins % $duration);
mt_srand($seed);

// use mt_rand to build an 'order by'
// array that will change every $duration
$orderBy = array_map(function() {
    return mt_rand();
}, range(1, count($id)));

// sort $ids against $orderBy
array_multisort($orderBy, $id);

$orderBy = array_map(function() {
    return mt_rand();
}, range(1, count($status)));
array_multisort($orderBy, $status);

$orderBy = array_map(function() {
    return mt_rand();
}, range(1, count($online)));
array_multisort($orderBy, $online);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $results1 = array_pop($id);
    $results2 = array_pop($status);
    echo "                            <td>{$results1[0]}</td>\n";
    echo "                            <td>{$results1[1]}</td>\n";
    echo "                            <td><span class=\"{$results2[0]}\">{$results2[1]}</span></td>\n";
}
```

Comment: you are effectively writting a lot of loops complex - - can you please put it the input ouput of your algorithm so that we can see if we can shorten the code by known what to expect.

Comment: Could you please also state what this code does?  That should especially be in the title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part is duplicated:

> ```
> $orderBy = array_map(function() {
>     return mt_rand();
> }, range(1, count($id)));
> array_multisort($orderBy, $id);
> ```

You apply the same logic to `$id`, `$status`, `$online`.

To eliminate duplication, you can move this common logic to a function with one parameter:

```
function reorder(&$arr) {
    $orderBy = array_map(function() {
        return mt_rand();
    }, range(1, count($arr)));
    array_multisort($orderBy, $arr);
}
reorder($id);
reorder($status);
reorder($online);
```

Note that we pass the array by reference (`&$arr`), because `array_multisort` does the same, and modifies the content of the array anyway.

**UPDATE**

As other answers and comments have pointed out, you could also eliminate the magic numbers and duplication when creating the `$status` array, for example like this:

```
$color1 = array("red", "no");
$color2 = array("green", "yes");
$num_color1 = 7;
$num_color2 = 3;
$status = array_fill(0, $num_color1, $color1)
          + array_fill($num_color1, $num_color2, $color2);
```

Answer (score 10):

Extract some constants:

replace

```
// 70% chance of red an 30% of green
$status = array(
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("red", "no"),
    array("green", "yes"),
    array("green", "yes"),
    array("green", "yes")
);
```

by:

```
// 70% chance of red an 30% of green
$red = array("red", "no");
$green = array("green", "yes");
$status = array($red, $red, $red, $red, $red, $red, $red, $green, $green, $green);
```

Comment: The above code can be further re factored by avoiding [magic numbers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber) i.e. you can use a constant like: `define("COLOR_RED", "red")` and then use this constant identifier in you code.

Comment: This could be even more elegant with array_fill: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php

Comment: @vivekpoddar: I am not a php programmer. You are right defining `$red = array("red", "no");` (and also `$green`) as a constant would be an improvement.

Comment: @MrSmith42: I am not php programmer too ;)

Comment: @vivekpoddar: If you're going to use constants, they should have less specific names.  What happens when i want `COLOR_RED` to be `"blue"` instead?  :P  (And if that will never ever change, why constify it?)

Comment: A better approach would be to use a enum and use color names as a constants there. That way you can manage that as a single source of information about colors and hence keep your code dry.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you want your script to output a list of user ids, usernames, and online status. Each user has a 30% chance of being online and the list changes randomly every 5 minutes. If I'm wrong about any of that please correct me.

These lines of code don't affect the output.

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2014);
$rate = 1 / 30;
$amount = number_format(floor((time() - $start) * $rate));

$online = range(7, 21);

$orderBy = array_map(function() {
    return mt_rand();
}, range(1, count($online)));
array_multisort($orderBy, $online);
```

- Your seed changes every five minutes, but loops every hour. This gives you just 12 possible seeds.
- For the online status, inside your loop generate a true/false value that has a certain probability of being true. This requires fewer lines of code and the maximum number of ids is not limited by the size of your status array.
- Use $i as an index to the array rather than poping elements.
- Don't print extra white space with your HTML, unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

The modified code:

```
// 30% chance of being online
$ONLINE_PROB = 0.3;

// create and assign a 'seed' value that changes 
// every $DURATION seconds and assign to mt_srand
$DURATION = 5*60;
mt_srand(floor(time()/$DURATION));

$id = array(
  array("42706686", "rebel2america"),
  array("100004055720670", "marquez.candace"),
  array("100000756492404", "vince.goode.3"),
  array("100007763585373", "laura.allen.75491"),
);
// randomly shuffle $id
$orderBy = array_map(function(){return mt_rand();},range(1,count($id)));
array_multisort($orderBy,$id);

for($i=0; $i<count($id); ++$i)
{
  echo "<td>{$id[$i][0]}</td><td>{$id[$i][1]}</td>";
  if(mt_rand()/mt_getrandmax() <= $ONLINE_PROB)
    echo "<td><span class=\"green\">yes</span></td>";
  else
    echo "<td><span class=\"red\">no</span></td>";
}
```